# Paste Issue in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: windows-10, libreoffice-writer

I’m having a bizarre issue while working in LibreOffice Writer.  No matter what I copy, while pasting it into the document (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>V</kbd>), it does not get pasted into the document text at the cursor position.  Instead, a floating object that looks like a text box gets created and the pasting gets performed into that.

[image]

The clipboard content is simple things like plain text or Internet addresses, no unusual or complex content, and it pastes normally into other applications, like Notepad.  I'm using the same procedure and types of content that I've used successfully for three months without a problem. This behavior started suddenly a couple of days ago.

Closing and reopening the document does not help.  Sometimes restarting solves the problem but not always. Once the problem starts to happen, it affects all the documents (even in LibreOffice Calc).

Comment: What OS do you use? Since when this issue exists? Have you tried restarting your pc? Does if affect multiple documents?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. I'm facing this issue from the last couple of days. Sometimes restarting solves the problem but not always. Once the problem starts to happen, it affects all the documents (even in LibreOffice calc)

Comment: Are you getting something totally random, or is it the previous thing you saved to the clipboard?

Comment: What you're describing doesn't sound like a feature you aren't using correctly, it sounds like something is corrupted.  If it happens with multiple LO apps but nothing else, it might be worth uninstalling LO and reinstalling it.  It also might be worth checking whether people are reporting LO compatibility problems with Win 10.

Comment: For an example, Let's say I have copied an internet address. When I paste it in writer, it paste as an anchor text. But while in notepad, its working fine.

Comment: When you insert something like a text box, you can put it anywhere; it doesn't get inserted at the next character position of the page text.  LO Writer stores it's location as a position relative to something on the page.  If you turn on display of non-printing characters, page layout placeholders are shown.  If you select a floating element like the text box, the anchor will be displayed to identify what on the page it is "anchored" to.  I wonder if instead of simply pasting from the clipboard, you're inserting it as an object.  What's the paste procedure you use?

Comment: I simply press ctrl + V. I'm using LO Writer for almost 3 months. It never had any paste issue.

Comment: @KinameCole, so you're just within the document text, with a visible cursor position.  You use ctrl-V; you don't do any kind of insert, like a text box.  And after ctrl-V, the insert is sitting in a floating object that wasn't there before? (The question is showing a text box or shape or something that you're pasting into.)  If that's the case, something isn't working normally.  I'm not even aware of keyboard shortcuts that could do that, which would seem to leave corruption.  Is it reliable or intermittent?  If you close the document and reopen it, does the problem recur?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Something isn't working normally. No, I didn't do any kind of insert or anything else. Simply ctrl+V and there the image you're looking. Yes, no matter how many times you close the document, the problem remains the same. I'm leaving LibreOffice. Thank you @fixer1234 for your efforts.

Comment: @KinameCole, the problem could be just that something got corrupted (the document, the template, LO itself), or that LO has some compatibility issues with Win 10 (in which case, a compatibility setting might fix it). Don't know how much patience you have to pursue it, but you could try opening a new document with the default template to see if it's document or template-related. If not, uninstall, download the latest stable version of LO, reinstall using compatibility with say Win 7, then open a new document with the default template and test. This would be widely reported if a typical problem.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to reinstall using compatibility settings one last time. Thank you @fixer1234

Comment: @KinameCole, I'm curious.  Did reinstalling fix this?  However you finally resolve this, it would be helpful to others with a similar problem if you could close the loop by posting a short answer with whatever your solution was, and the results of what you tried (even if you couldn't fix it and just moved on to other software).  As is, your question is a [cliffhanger](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cliffhanger).  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Reinstalled and then restarted. The issue is fixed for now. Let's see if this comes again. Thank you.